# When will the pushforward of a structure sheaf still be a structure sheaf?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes.

1. When $PicY\rightarrow PicX$ is an embedding and $f_{*}\mathscr{O}_{X}$ is invertible, it is the structure sheaf of $Y$.
2. In the proof of Zariski's Main Theorem, we have: If $f$ is birational, finite, integral, and $Y$ is normal, then $f_{*}\mathscr{O}_{X}$ is the structure sheaf of $Y$.

My questions are

1) What exactly prevent $f_{*}\mathscr{O}_{X}$ to be a structure sheaf?

2) Is there any necessary and sufficient condition(s) guarantee that $f_{*}\mathscr{O}_{X}$ is a structure sheaf?

Comment: In the first claim, the assumption on Picard groups is not needed: if $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is invertible, then the natural map $\mathcal{O}_Y\to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is an isomorphism. Working locally, this just means that if $g:A\to B$ is a ring homomorphism such that $B$ is a free $A$-module of rank $1$, then $f$ is an isomorphism. If $b\in B$, multiplication by $b$ is $A$-linear, hence is multiplication by some $f(a)$. In particular $b1_B=f(a)1_B$, hence $b=f(a)$.

Comment: After reading the answers below, I want to add a small warning that some of them are false unless one also assumes that $X$ is integral, or at least reduced. For example, if $Y = Spec k[t]$ and $X = Spec k[t,x]/(x^2,xt)$ then $f:X \to Y$ is finite hence projective, and has connected fibres, and $Y$ is normal, but it does not hold that $f_*\mathcal O_X = \mathcal O_S$. To fix this, one checks easily that $\mathcal O_X(X)$ is a domain if $X$ is integral, then modifies the statements below by adding the assumption that $X$ be integral in many places.

Comment: Ps. I know this is an old question, but it seems quite a few people (including students) are still reading it, hence the comments.

Comment: @DavidHolmes: actually there are much more pathological counterexamples. For example, consider the relative (wrt $\bar{\mathbb F}_p$) Frobenius morphism $F \colon \mathbb P^1_{\bar{\mathbb F}_p} \to \mathbb P^1_{\bar{\mathbb F}_p}$. It is projective with geometrically connected fibres, and both sides are smooth geometrically integral varieties. Yet $F_*\mathcal O_X \neq \mathcal O_Y$, since it is a degree $p$ finite flat morphism. For a flat projective morphism, it suffices to have geometrically connected and geometrically reduced fibres, but I'm not sure what to do without flatness.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Hi Remy, you're quite right, thanks for pointing this out. In case it is helpful for someone, a reference for the statement `For a flat projective [or proper] morphism, it suffices to have geometrically connected and geometrically reduced fibres' is [FGA explained, ex. 9.3.11] - solution towards the end of the book. I will try to think more about the non-flat case at some point...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Q**: Exactly what information is contained in $f_*\mathscr O_X$?  Look at the
definition.  For any $U\subseteq Y$ open, $f_*\mathscr O_X(U) = \mathscr O_X(f^{-1}(U))$ =
regular functions on $f^{-1}(U)$.  So the information in $f_*\mathscr O_X$ is related
to the sets in $X$ of form $f^{-1}(U)$.

Cases where $f_*\mathscr O_X$ contains as little information about $X$ as possible.

If $X$ is irreducible and projective and $f$ is constant, e.g. if $Y$ is affine, then
the only non empty set of form $f^{-1}(U)$ in $X$ is $X$ itself.  In this case
$f_*\mathscr O_X$ is a skyscraper sheaf with stalk $k$ supported on the image point
of $f$ in $Y$.  There is very little information here about $X$, but perhaps we do
see that $f$ is constant and that $X$ is connected.  More generally, if $Z$ is a
projective variety, $Y$ is any variety, and $X = Z\times Y$, and $f:Z\times Y\to Y$
is the projection, then $f^{-1}(U) = Z\times U$, so an element of $f_*\mathscr
O_X(U)$, i.e. a regular function on $f^{-1}(U)$, is determined by its restriction to
$\{p\}\times U$ for any $p\in X$, i.e., a regular function on $U$ in $Y$.  Thus in
this case we have $f_*\mathscr O_X = \mathscr O_Y$.  Consequently in this case
$f_*\mathscr O_X$ recovers $Y$, but contains no information at all about $X$.

In general, if $f:X\to Y$ is a projective morphism with every fiber connected, and
$Y$ is any normal variety, then $f_*\mathscr O_X = \mathscr O_Y$, so again
$f_*\mathscr O_X$ contains little information about $X$.  Recall that if $X$ is a
projective variety then every morphism out of $X$ is a projective morphism, and more
generally a projective morphism $X\to Y$ is one that factors via an isomorphism of X
with a closed subvariety of $\mathbb P^n\times Y$, followed by the projection
$\mathbb P^n\times Y\to Y$.  Suppose that $f:X\to Y$ is any projective morphism.
Then the fibers $f^{-1}(y)$ over points $y \in Y$ are all finite unions of projective
varieties.  Therefore for any open set $U\subseteq Y$ containing the point $y$, the
only regular functions in $\mathscr O_X(f^{-1}(U)) = f_*\mathscr O_X(U)$ are constant
on every connected component of the fiber $f^{-1}(y)$.  Thus $f_*\mathscr O_X$ can
contain little information about $X$ and $f$, other than at most the connected
components of the fibers.  We shall see below that it contains exactly this
information.

Cases where $f_*\mathscr O_X$ contains as much information about $X$ as possible.

If $f:X\to Y$ is a map of affine varieties, then the global sections of $f_*\mathscr
O_X$ determine $X$ completely, since then $H^0(Y,f_*\mathscr O_X) = H^0(X,\mathscr
O_X)$, and then $X = \mathrm{Spec}h^0(X,\mathscr O_X)$, is the unique affine variety
with coordinate ring $H^0(X,\mathscr O_X)$.  The generalization of this case is that
of any affine map $f:X\to Y$, since then $X$ can be recovered by patching together
the analogous construction from $H^0(U,f_*\mathscr O_X)$ for affine open sets
$U\subseteq Y$.  Thus $X$ is completely determined by $f_*\mathscr O_X$ for any
affine map $f:X\to Y$, and this is essentially the only case.  I.e. in general
$f_*\mathscr O_X$ is always a quasi coherent $\mathscr O_Y$ algebra, and if we want
it to determine a variety, as opposed to a "scheme", it is reasonable to assume for
all $U\subseteq Y$ affine open, that $f_*\mathscr O_X(U)$ is a finitely generated k
algebra, as well as an $\mathscr O_Y(U)$ algebra.  We may call temporarily such an
$\mathscr O_Y$ algebra "of finite type".  Thus if $f:X\to Y$ is any morphism such that
$f_*\mathscr O_X$ is of finite type, then the patching construction above yields not
necessarily $X$, but a variety $Z$ and an affine map $h:Z\to Y$ which factors via a
map $g:X\to Z$, where $f = h\circ g$, and where $g_*(\mathscr O_X) = \mathscr O_Z$.
In particular then, we have $f_*\mathscr O_X = (h\circ g)_*(\mathscr O_X) =
h_*(g_*(\mathscr O_X))= h_*(\mathscr O_Z)$.  So since $h$ is affine, $f_*\mathscr O_X =
h_*(\mathscr O_Z)$ determines not $X$, but $Z$.  (Kempf, section 6.5.)

The case of an arbitrary projective morphism.

Now when $f:X\to Y$ is any projective morphism, then $f_*\mathscr O_X$ is a coherent
$\mathscr O_Y$-module, hence we get a factorization of $f$ as $h\circ g:X\to Z\to Y$,
where $h:Z\to Y$ is affine, and where also $h_*(\mathscr O_Z) = f_*\mathscr O_X$.
Then $h$ is not only an affine map, but since $h_*(\mathscr O_Z)$ is a coherent $\mathscr
O_Y$-module, $h$ is also a finite map.  Moreover $g:X\to Z$ is also projective and since
$g_*(\mathscr O_X) = \mathscr O_Z$, it can be shown that the fibers of $g$ are connected.
Hence an arbitrary projective map $f$ factors through a projective map g with connected
fibers, followed by a finite map $h$.  Thus in this case, the algebra $f_*\mathscr O_X$
determines exactly the finite part $h:Z\to Y$ of $f$, whose points over $y$ are precisely
the connected components of the fiber $f^{-1}(y)$.

One corollary of this is "Zariski's connectedness theorem".  If $f:X\to Y$ is projective
and birational, and $Y$ is normal then $f_*\mathscr O_X= \mathscr O_Y$, and all fibers
of $f$ are connected, since in this case $Z = Y$ in the Stein factorization described
above.  If we assume in addition that $f$ is quasi finite, i.e. has finite fibers, then
$f$ is an isomorphism.  More generally, if $Y$ is normal and $f:X\to Y$ is any birational,
quasi - finite, morphism, then $f$ is an embedding onto an open subset of $Y$ ("Zariski's
'main theorem' ").  More generally still, any quasi finite morphism factors through
an open embedding and a finite morphism.

Comment: The claim `In general, if $f:X\to Y$ is a projective morphism with every fiber connected, and $Y$ is any normal variety, then $f_* \mathcal O_X = \mathcal O_Y$' needs the assumption that $X$ be reduced, see example in comment above.

Comment: There are even worse counterexamples in characteristic $p > 0$, even when both $X$ and $Y$ are geometrically integral, smooth, etc. See my comment above.

Answer (score 16):

Let me try to write an informal explanation as to why (and why not) you might have $f_* \mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}_Y$.  This is basically what J.C. Ottem wrote, but I'm trying to explain the reason at a slightly more philosophical level.

Now $O_X$ is the sheaf of regular functions on $X$.  Given an open set $U \subseteq Y$, the sections $\Gamma(U, f_* \mathcal{O}_X)$ is just $\Gamma(f^{-1}(U), \mathcal{O}_X)$.  For this to be viewed as even a subset of functions on $U$, you would expect it to be constant / well-defined at the points of $U$.  So consider some (closed) point $z \in U$.  Therefore, you need a section $\sigma \in \Gamma(f^{-1}(U), \mathcal{O}_X)$ to be constant on the fiber $f^{-1}(z)$.  Since $f$ is proper, this fiber is also proper, and thus the only sections are constant.  I just lied of course, the only sections are the functions that are constant on each *connected component* of the fiber.

Thus if you have fibers with multiple connected components, then you will expect that some of the sections $\sigma$ might be able to distinguish those connected components, and thus those sections of $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$ can't be viewed as functions on $Y$.

Why does normality come into play?  Well, the picture isn't quite as simple as what I just described.  If a scheme $Z$ is non-normal, and its normalization $Z' \to Z$ is injective/bijective (for example, the normalization of the cusp), then you should view that normalization map as the inclusion of all the ``algebraic functions'' which can be defined on the points.

In fact, given any scheme $Z$ over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, the *seminormalization* $Z'$ of $Z$ can be exactly described as ``the scheme whose structure sheaf has all functions that make sense on the closed points of $Z$.''

This is the point of view on seminormalization is described in:
Leahy and Vitulli, *Seminormal rings and weakly normal varieties.*  Nagoya Math. J.  82  (1981), 27–56

Answer (score 13):

If $f:X\to Y$ is a proper morphism of noetherian shemes, then $f_*O_X=O_Y$ says that the fibers of $f$ are connected. This follows from a general form of Zariski's main theorem (Hartshorne III.11.3).

Conversely, if $Y$ is in addition normal, then $f_*O_X=O_X$ holds. Indeed, there is a Stein factorization of the form
$$
X \xrightarrow{f'}  Z={\bf Spec} (f_* O_X) \xrightarrow{g} Y
$$where $g$ is finite and $f'$ has connected fibers. Furthermore $g_*O_Z=O_Y$ and 
${f'}_*O_X=O_Z$. If the fibers of $f$ are connected, then $g$ must be birational (by Hartshorne III.10.3) and is in fact an isomorphism if $Y$ is normal. It follows that $f_*O_X=O_Y$ if and only if $f$ has connected fibers.

Comment: A minor correciton, if $Y$ is normal and $f$ has connected fibers, then $f_* \mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}_Y$ holds in characteristic zero.  In characteristic $p$, this is not the case (for example the Frobenius morphism).  

Comment: Yes, that's true. In that case $g$ is bijective, but not necessarily an isomorphism.

Comment: Another quick comment, one can do even better than normality.  Let's work over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.  With J.C. Ottem's notation, assume that $f$ has connected fibers and $Y$ is *seminormal*.  Doing Stein factorization as above, one has $g : Z \to Y$ a finite map, which is birational (at least in characteristic zero).  Furthermore, one can show that $g$ also has connected fibers because $f'$ is surjective (since it is proper and dominant).  Thus $g$ is an isomorphism by the defining property of seminormality (over algebraicaly closed field of char. 0).

Comment: Is the reference to Hartshorne III.10.3 correct?


Comment: I think the reference to III.10.3 is incorrect, or at least it points to something irrelevant in the edition I have to hand. Also, the statement `if $Y$ is in addition normal, then $f_∗\mathcal O_X=\mathcal O_S$ holds' needs $X$ reduced even in characteristic zero, see comment above.

Comment: And for those of us lucky enough to have non-algebraically closed fields in our lives: the assumption should be that $f$ has *geometrically* connected fibres, rather than merely connected. An easy counterexample is a field extension.

Answer (score 4):

Another issue that has not been addressed is what happens if $f$ is not proper. You may have intended to assume that it is, but it also an interesting question for not necessarily proper morphisms. For that matter, you could ask "if $f:X\hookrightarrow Y$ is an open embedding, when will $f_*\mathscr O_X$ be isomorphic to $\mathscr O_Y$?" You are also writing that "... if $f_*\mathscr O_X$ is a line bundle, then ...". It should be noted that this is actually a strong restriction. For instance if you have a generically finite morphism that satisfies this, then it has to be birational.

For the question of an open embedding the answer is relatively simple. If the complement of $X$ in $Y$ has a non-empty codimension $1$ part, then $f_*\mathscr O_X$ is not even coherent, so little chance there. If the complement is of codimension at least $2$, then this is a condition on the singularities of $Y\setminus X$, and essentially equivalent to $Y$ being $S_2$ along $X\setminus Y$.