# push-forward of the structure sheaf, stein factorization, birational and connected fibers 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am confused with the following observation: Let $f : X:=\mathrm{Spec}(K) \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(k) =: Y$ be a scheme morphism corresponding to a non-trivial finite field extension ( hence $f$ is proper and $X$, $Y$ are noetherian). Its Stein factorization is $ X \overset { \mathrm{id}_X} \longrightarrow X \overset {f} \longrightarrow Y$. But it's clear that $f$ is not a birational, even if $char=0$.  We don't have

$f_{*} \mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}_Y$

in this example ( $char = 0 $ or not) either, although we have $f$ has connected fiber and $Y$ is normal.

---

When I read the following discussion, I got a question.

> [When will the pushforward of a structure sheaf still be a structure sheaf?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63301/when-will-the-pushforward-of-a-structure-sheaf-still-be-a-structure-sheaf)

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a proper morphism of noetherian shcemes and $ X \overset {f'}  \rightarrow Z \overset {g} \rightarrow Y$ be its Stein factorization. In J.C. Ottem response, he mentioned that if the fibers of $f$ are connected, then $g$ must be birational ( I think that we assume both $X$ and $Y$ are integral schemes), and from this, one gets $g_{*} \mathcal{O}_Z = \mathcal{O}_Y$, hence we have

$f_{*} \mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}_Y$

He also give the reference, which is Hartshorne III.10.3, for which I think the right one is Hartshorne III.11.3, but 11.3 is telling that the isomorphism gives connected fibers.

So I would like to know :

(1) How to see that $g$ is birational? The correct reference?

(2) In which part we need the characteristic 0 condition?

(3) Could we replace the characteristic 0 condition to another condition, e.g $f$ has integral fibers?

Comment: 1), 2) The fact that $g$ is birational follows from generic smoothness in characteristic zero and the reference is Hartshorne III.10.7 (and not III.10.3). I don't know if there is an analogue to the characteristic $p$ case.

Comment: You need to assume that the fibres are geometrically connected in order to get $g$ to be birational (in characteristic $0$). Over a field of characteristic $p>0$ it suffices to assume that the fibres are geometrically connected and geometrically reduced. This follows from the elementary fact that if $k$ is a field and $A$ is a finite $k$-algebra then $Spec(A)$ is geometrically connected and reduced iff $A = k$ (as a $k$-algebra).

Comment: Sorry, in my first comment I misread what was said.  I got $f$ and $f'$ confused.

Comment: ulrich, a dumb question when you say that ``$A$ is a finite $k$-algebra'', you mean a finite as a $k$-vector space, not finitely generated right?

Comment: @ Karl, yes and it should be finite as a $k$-vector space here to get the conclusion also. And I think that finite algebra is the common terminology for algebras which are finite as modules (over base ring), see p.30 of Atiyah & Macdonald's book "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" 